# Where do I find "torrc" file in Tor 6.0.1? Is torrc-defaults the same as torrc?

Tags: configuration, onion-services, mac

I want to set up a Hidden Service on OSX and I've been following these instructions on the Tor site: https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-hidden-service.html.en#two. I was able to do step 1 and set up a localhost server on my computer. I then downloaded & installed xcode, macports and tor browser like it says in step 2. My problem is that it says to edit the "torrc" file and paste the text in step 2 (which is something like this:

```
HiddenServiceDir /opt/local/var/lib/tor/hidden_service/
HiddenServicePort 80 127.0.0.1:80
```

but then the version of Tor (6.0.1) for my OSX (Yosemite) doesn't have a "torrc" file, only a "torrc-defaults" file—which doesn't contain a section for Hidden Services—and when I try to alter it by pasting the above code and re-opening Tor, I get an error message and Tor won't open. Anyone have  suggestions as to what I'm getting wrong here? Also, I have a Dynamic IP address, will this cause problems setting up a Hidden Service? Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my post [here](http://www.discuzfeed.com/tor/hzopp-creating-exitnodes-command-for-tor-6-0-on-a-mac.html) or the location of torrc for Tor6.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. And sorry for my ignorance (very new to all of this!), but I cannot find the "TorBrowser-Data" folder either. Where should I look? I can only find the "TorBrowser-6.0.1-osx64_en-US.dmg" and then the Tor application. When I "show package contents" of the application the "torrc" file isn't there.

Comment: Wait a minute. I just found it in the Applications Support folder. Please disregard my last comment and thanks for your help!!

Comment: Hmm, maybe they change it for 6.0.1 vs. 6.0.  It used to be in the same folder as Tor6  app but maybe they read my comments in my thread and took my suggestion about correctly placing it in ~/Library/Applications Support.  That's great :-)  I can get rid of my symlink now.

Comment: @TorToronto123 - you should check that the ~/Library/Application Support/TorBrowser-Data is actually the one you are using and that there isn't a TorBrowser-Data folder in the same directory as your Tor6 app.  I just experimented with seeing if Tor6.0.1 would access TorBrowser-Data in Application Support by removing the symlink I had in the Tor6 folder.  It didn't.  Instead it created a new TorBrowser-Data folder in the Tor6 folder.  So I think it still looks for TorBrowser-Data in the app folder and not Application Support.  At least that is what I am seeing.

Comment: The link is dead or goes to some random spam page.